Managing menus in "The Store" theme
Here https://www.softedu-magazin.ro/ I have 2 menus. Can't rid off the upper one despite all my efforts. If I hide items from one menu they disappear also from the other.
Any ideea please?



You have the same menu assigned to both locations. In order to decouple them you need to deselect "menu-principal" from the Top Menu location.
It's possible the theme may try to automatically populate a location when no menu is assigned. If this is the case, create a new menu with no items and assign it.
